# My first custom module

Tags: 7, forms

I found [some code](http://drupal.org/node/1252144#comment-5826316) on the Drupal forum that solves a problem I have. Several users report the code works for them so I suppose I did not exactly get how to create a custom module. I followed the following steps:

Create a folder called `i18nblocktran` in sites/all/module and added two files:

**i18nblocktran.info**

```
; $Id$

name = Wysiwyg taxonomy translation
description = Displays the wysiwyg editor in the taxonomy term translation interface 
package = Nathan
core = 7.x 
files[] = i18nblocktran.module
```

and **i18nblocktran.module**

```
<?php
function i18nblocktran_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'i18n_string_translate_page_form'){
    foreach($form['strings'] as $name => $field){
      if(preg_match('/blocks:block:[0-9]+:body/i',$name)){
        // Change textarea to text_format
        $form['strings'][$name]['#type'] = 'text_format';
        $form['strings'][$name]['#description'] = '<br/>';
      }
    }
    $form['#submit'] = array_merge(array('i18nblocktran_string_translate_page_form_submit'), $form['#submit']);
  }
}

function i18nblocktran_string_translate_page_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Remove wysiwyg format because i18n cant handle it
  foreach($form_state['values']['strings'] AS $name => $field) {
    if(preg_match('/blocks:block:[0-9]+:body/i',$name)){
      unset($form_state['values']['strings'][$name]['format']);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Then I activated the module in the admin but nothing happened. What did I miss ?

Comment: have you tried to flush cache ?

Comment: @HoverFusion: yes

Comment: have you looked into drupal logs or php logs for possible error ? What about condition in if clausule, if is it not met ? Try to put simple echo in module, to see if it is "working" by initial setup...

Comment: you're adding a submit handler called `mymodule_string_translate_page_form_submit` instead of `i18nblocktran_string_translate_page_form_submit` to the form.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for pointing this out but it did not solve...

Comment: @NathanZ as HoverFusion suggested, you can put a `dpm()` at various places in the code to check if execution ever reaches there. Is the form alter being run? Is the preg_match matching? Is the submit handler being called? Is that preg_match matching?

Comment: There could be a better alternative to preg_match as well. Try dsm()'ing $form

Comment: @andy: using `dpm()` pointed me to the right direction and I solved the problem. If you want to copy your comment in an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a submit handler called `mymodule_string_translate_page_form_submit` instead of `i18nblocktran_string_translate_page_form_submit` to the form. After that, as NenadP suggested, you can put a `dpm()` at various places in the code to check if execution ever reaches there. Is the form alter being run? Is the preg_match matching? Is the submit handler being called? Is that preg_match matching?

Answer (score 3):

Change line 4 in your .module file

```
foreach($form['strings'] as $name => $field){
```

with this

```
foreach($form['strings']['all'] as $name => $field){
```

It should do the job

Answer (score 1):

```
function i18nblocktran_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'i18n_string_translate_page_form'){
    foreach($form['strings']['all'] as $name => $field){
          if(preg_match('/blocks:block:[0-9]+:body/i',$name)){
              $form['strings']['all'][$name]['#type'] = 'text_format';
              $form['strings']['all'][$name]['#description'] = '<br/>';
          }
      }
      $form['#submit'] = array_merge(array('i18nblocktran_string_translate_page_form_submit'), $form['#submit']);
  }
}
```

You have missed the ['all'] in the foreach statement as well as in the foreach loop.